How can I load data into the TWebTableControl in TMS WEB Core?
I have a TWebTableControl that I need to load data into, but I do not understand how to do this.

I do not understand the documentation either: https://download.tmssoftware.com/doc/tmswebcore/components/twebtablecontrol/
It says to use TableControl.Cells[col,row]: string;, but how?
My table's name is tblCoupons. I have no idea how to load data into this table. Can anyone help with a code example or guide, please?

Here's a code example to put data into the TWebTableControl:
var
  I: UInt64;
begin
  TableControl.ColCount := 4;
  TableControl.RowCount := 1;

  TableControl.Cells[0,0] := 'First Column Heading';
  TableControl.Cells[1,0] := 'Second Column Heading';
  TableControl.Cells[2,0] := 'Third Column Heading';
  TableControl.Cells[3,0] := 'Fourth Column Heading';

  For I := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    TableControl.RowCount := TableControl.RowCount + 1;

    TableControl.Cells[0,I] := 'Random Data col_1 for Row ' + I.ToString;
    TableControl.Cells[1,I] := 'Random Data col_2 for Row ' + I.ToString;
    TableControl.Cells[2,I] := 'Random Data col_3 for Row ' + I.ToString;
    TableControl.Cells[3,I] := 'Random Data col_4 for Row ' + I.ToString;
  end;
end;

TableControl being the name of your table component.
This is what the above code will generate in a default TWebTableControl component:

